# What header should I use to indicate the stability of the API?

Tags: http-headers, api-design

I have an API with multiple versions.

I'm using path-based versioning (e.g. `/api/v1/widgets`, `/api/v2/widgets`)

Each version goes through a lifecycle: alpha, beta, GA, deprecated, etc.

I'd like to use a response header to indicate the corresponding 'stability' of the API.  That way clients can check that if the value in the response header is 'alpha', they need to expect changes in the response.

I'm currently using a custom header 'x-api-stability'.

However, it feels like their should be a better way of doing this.  Is there a standard for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think there is a big risk using custom headers like this as you are assuming they will be checked. Plus it adds extra overhead for the caller to check *every* call to make sure what they are calling is now stable. Finally, what should a caller do if header says this version is not stable? Again, lots of unnecessary overhead.

Normally you just publish which version of your API is the latest using your online docs etc. That's a cleaner approach as it allows for explanations around the latest versions, endpoint updates, new features, and depreciation policy. Trying to embed this into your endpoints makes everything more complicated and it's unnecessary.